# How to change destination of back button to another storyboard iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, back

I have an application with the flow bellow:

1. Main storyboard: Navigation A -> ViewController A1 (first screen of my app) ... go to some screens and go to other storyboard.
2. Second storyboard: Navigation B -> ViewController B1 -> ViewController B2 -> ViewController B3.

The normal logic when I'm in B3, tap back button back to B2 and tap back again back to B1 ... 
Now I want from B3 go to A1 by click back button. I use this code

```
UIStoryboard *Main = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];


UIViewController *theTabBar = (UIViewController *)[Main instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:theTabBar animated:YES];
```

But it not work as I want (on Main appeared the back button, that was wrong), I changed pushViewController to popViewController but it not work too.

Comment: you looking for UnwindSegue http://www.raywenderlich.com/113394/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2

Comment: just don't do such thing, it confuses your end-user as hell, and if the navigation is not predictable, you may take a risk to fail the review procedure as well.

Comment: remove navigation B from second storyboard and directly push viewcontroller B1 from first navigation controller.

Comment: @holex thank you but I don't have the choice, that ideal from my client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just right this code on back button of b3:-

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"takeBack" object:nil];
```

and write this code on view viewwillappear of A1:-

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(popping) name:@"takeBack" object:nil];
}
-(void)popping{
    NSUInteger index=-1;

    for (UIViewController *view in [self.navigationController viewControllers]) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {
            index=[[self.navigationController viewControllers] indexOfObject:view];
        }
    }

    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:index] animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not work. I don't see anything happen, I have a question why index = -1?

Comment: it is working i've checked it practically. We've initialised index to -1 because -1 is not the index of any controller.

Comment: Could you share me the test project? Thank you.

Comment: My project didn't pushing controller as your way. I used storyboard https://www.dropbox.com/s/n486bcbfx64ekin/storyboard.png?dl=0. Maybe it not work for me. Do you have another way?

Comment: I resolved my problem by another way, but I used a little of your codes. Thank you very much.